# Azure service dies after a few days

Tags: azure, memory-leaks, virtual

I have Small size (x2) cloud service running and operating just fine for 4-6 days but then it becomes unresponsive and requires manual restart through Azure portal to get it back online.

Windows event logs show that virtual memory is running low. After 2-3 days I start getting:

> Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The
>   following programs consumed the most virtual memory: WaIISHost.exe
>   (3836) consumed 3810709504 bytes, CacheService.exe (1528) consumed
>   823902208 bytes, and w3wp.exe (1728) consumed 145485824 bytes.

After a while services start failing (due to memory problem??):

> Application: CacheService.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled
>   exception.                 Exception Info:
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ConfigStoreException
>   Stack:                    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.CustomProviderProxy+<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_3(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)                 at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()                    at
>   System.Threading.*ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>
>   |http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>1026200x800000000000001138ApplicationRD00155D45A2ADApplication:
>   CacheService.exe               Framework Version: v4.0.30319               Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
>   Exception Info:
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ConfigStoreException
>
>   Stack:                    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.CustomProviderProxy+<>c*_DisplayClass5.<PerformOperation>b__3(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)                 at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()                    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

and eventually Http requests start failing:

> Process information:
>       Process ID: 3344
>       Process name: w3wp.exe
>       Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>          Exception information:
>       Exception type: HttpException
>       Exception message: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AF)          at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
>   The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AF)

I'm not sure if the problem is that virtual memory is configured too low, or is the use of the memory too high. WaIISHost.exe virtual memory use definitely looks quite high, but it seems to stabilize at around 4.1 GB.

I do not know why WaIISHost.exe would need so much, since the Run() method is doing just very light housekeeping activities, such as pinging the site every few minutes to keep the Application running during daytime.

Available Memory monitoring in Azure Portal shows the service to have 300-800MB of free memory during the whole period before the crash.

Any ideas what is the problem? How can I configure virtual memory higher?

Comment: You clearly have a memory leak of some kind. Any variables (static or otherwise) that you keep around? Logs? Collections? Even something creating via a Dependency Injection framework, possibly? In the meantime, you could always write a simple PowerShell script to reboot the instance nightly until you figure this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a memory leak in your app code, what you are catching in the Azure exceptions is just the after effect of your environment running out of memory because of app code consuming all of it, from my experience.

Normally when I would RDP into the box identify the process that has the memory leak and then start a profiling session of your code with Redgate tool (or any other tool). Then run your process for half a day with that tool and you should easily identify what the problem is.

You will probably find I would guess that is something like an exception that is causing your code to not clean up correctly. That would explain why you would see this problem after a couple of days and couple of exceptions. I would look at your exception handling and clean up code.  You should test for disconnects in your code base and other transient positions that might effect your code.

I would also stick in something like newrelic or foglight so that you get a clear heads up that you code/Azure instance is about to fail you can also see what timescales are on your failures and possible get more logging info and if there is anything that is causing the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Despite @JamesKn only having 1 StackOverflow point, this is VERY GOOD advice! Listen to James!

Comment: Thank's for a good advice and pointer to good tools. Redgate ANTS really helps with debugging the memory leak.